# ExtJS Ajax (JSON) post not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs

I have seen a couple of examples from stackoverflow itself and also in the extjs documentation. But all I can see is 404 error.

```
       Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/project-desktop-service/decisions.json',
            method: 'post',        
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            params: {
                rolename: 'rolename'
            },
            success: function(){console.log('success');},
            failure: function(){console.log('failure');}
        });
```

I also have tried different combinations of removing and adding the content type, adding absolute url etc. But the result is the same failure everytime.

Comment: The best way to debug this is to separate the URL from Ext JS altogether and test it by itself. Once you *know* that the URL is valid, then you can start using it in Ext JS. If you've got a working URL, you'll only compound the frustration by trying to debug what is fundamentally a server issue by using Ext JS.

Comment: Did you call it from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

from Wiki :

```
  The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that 
  the client was able to communicate with the server, 
  but the server could not find what was requested.
```

the only thing is not function right is you URL or you request somthing that was not ther.